# hyperlink column in spservices

Tags: spservices, hyperlink

I am trying to get hyperlink type of column named as "Important Link". 
without
`var liHtml5="<li>" + ($(this).attr("ows_Important_x0020_Link")).split(", ")[0]+"</li>"`; other code works perfect. 
Please help. 
My SPservice code is as below:

```
$().SPServices({

            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "URL_List",
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='text'>"+ URL+ "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status)
            {
                    var itemCount = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount");
                    alert(itemCount);
                    if(itemCount == 0)
                    {
                        //check if URL contains slash
                        var SlashTesing=URL.indexOf("/") != -1;   
                        alert(SlashTesing);

                        if(SlashTesing== true)
                        {
                            NewURL=URL.substring(0,URL.lastIndexOf("/"));
                            gofunction(NewURL); 
                        }
                       else
                       {
                            var liHtml2="<h2>"+"Sorry...we dont have this info "+"</h2>";
                            $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml2);
                        }
                    }
                else
                {
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() 
                    {
                        var text="<h2>"+"Showing information for this URL :"+URL+"</h2>";
                        var liHtml2="<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Department") + "</h4>"+"</li>";
                        var liHtml3="<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Team") + "</h4>"+"</li>";
                        var liHtml4="<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_PointOfContact")+ "</h4>"+"</li>";
                        var liHtml5="<li>" + ($(this).attr("ows_Important_x0020_Link")).split(", ")[0]+"</li>";


                        $("#tasksUL").append(text);
                        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml2);
                        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml3);
                        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml4);
                        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml5);

                    });
                }
            }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

It should just be:

```
var liHtml5= "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Important_x0020_Link").split(", ")[0] + "</li>";
```

You have extra parans in there.

If the column isn't required then you need to adapt your code:

```
var liHtml5 = "";
var link = $(this).attr("ows_Important_x0020_Link");
if (link.length){
 liHtml5= "<li>" + link.split(", ")[0] + "</li>";
 $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml5);
}
```

Comment: no...it does not work..! It look like that hyperlink column should be mandatory..! if its "required" column then it works like charm..!
Any other way to get it worked.?

Comment: If it isn't a required column, then you'd need to check for it.

Comment: edited answer to include another option

Comment: didnt help..!still same issue.! Do you see any any reason behind it.?
Also I need to get person or group type of field...any thoughs? or should i post new thread?